# Large data rendering issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, large-data

What is the best way to render large data at the View? Is the some way to render it by portions?

Controller's action produce the large data set (1000x1000 matrix) and returns it to View. When I render it the browser hangs. The data is produced by the other service and I can not get it with a smaller portions.

Matrix is two dimensional array of INT values.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var result = ThirdPartyService.GetData();

    return View(result);
}
```

View code:

```
<table>             
        <% foreach (var x = 0; x < Model.Matrix.Count; x++) { %>
            <tr>
        <% foreach (var y = 0; y < Model.Matrix[x].Count; y++) { %>
            <td><% = Model.Matrix[x, y] %></td>
        <% } %>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: How the user is supposed to process all those data?

Comment: How do you deal with such a large set of data?  That's virtually useless to a user to view a 1000x1000 matrix.

Comment: On other hand if show as 1-pixel-per-data-point it give very modestly sized image...

Comment: it is a statistical data

Comment: Data visualization is a huge topic; we are going to need a lot more information, such as what kind of data, what "large" means, what you are rendering, what "by portions" means, who/what a "controller" is, 1000x1000 what (words? numbers? pixels?), what kind of "View" you are talking about. Showing what you have so far would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render an empty table and get the data from the server for using ajax to populate it. This way, you will download the layout and the data, but not the `<tr><td></td></tr>` content. If you do the math:

- `<tr></tr>` for each row gives you 9*1000 = 9000 bytes
- `<td></td>` for each cell in each row gives you 9*1000*1000 = 9000000 bytes
- Total: 9009000

You can reduce about 9 mb from the request and that's a lot!

Also, you can turn on GZip on the server so the data moves compressed.

Comment: "You can render an empty table" - I should render it with JavaScript?

Comment: just put `<table id="data"></table>` in your markup and then populate it using ajax.

Comment: Where should I store the intermediate results? Controller's action call other service method, that returns this big matrix. Where is it better to put this matrix to make then the ajax requests to it?

Comment: The action that handles the ajax request will return the matrix, so you should execute the service method there.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that matrix that size isn't rendered whole on page, so my suggestion is to dynamically manipulate DOM, as user scrolls, by attaching to scroll event. This worked for me quite amazing, by using [SlickGird](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/) as data rendering component, with written custom plugin to handle auto-complete drop-down  with more than 1k elements. Browser has no problem with handling large data sets (I've tested up to 400k JS objects), but it definitely hangs when trying to display them. So just render the portion of the screen you're user is positioned at.

Comment: where I should to keep the matrix? I should save it to DB or in some other place?

Comment: actually it is rendered but it takes too much time and during it the browser do not answer. I need to work around it

Comment: You can consider saving client side using IndexedDB or localStorage (Search W3C or MDN for reference on these technologies). What's actually matrix element, is it complex object or just numeric value. If latter, you could keep it all in-memory (1000 x 1000 matrix would take no more then 4M + overhead) if we store number with 4B, 8M if stored with 8B, and so on.. )

Comment: Is it rendered whole on single page, or user has to scroll across the page. How does actual GUI representation look like?